# I get the error: Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, javafx

I have been trying to create a school management system but i get this error that i dont fully understand. This error ocurrus when i press the "Add Parent" button int the Parents.fxml, I've been trying to fix it but no luck:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1787)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1670)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
        at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3564)
        at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$8200(Scene.java:3492)
        at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3860)
        at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1200(Scene.java:3579)
        at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1849)
        at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2588)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:397)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:434)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:390)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:433)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:273)
        at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1782)
        ... 31 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3230)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3194)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3163)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3136)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3113)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3106)
        at sms.helpers.LoadResourcesHelper.loadFXML(LoadResourcesHelper.java:21)
        at sms.controllers.ParentsController.add_parent(ParentsController.java:20)
        ... 42 more
```

This is my Parents.fxml:
[Parents.fxml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I76BE.png)

This is my ParentsController which is linked with LoadResourcesHelper class:

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.control.Dialog;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
import sms.helpers.LoadResourcesHelper;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class ParentsController implements Initializable {
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    }

    @FXML
    public void add_parent(javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent event) {
        Parent root = LoadResourcesHelper.loadFXML("dialogs/add_parent");
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog();
        dialog.getDialogPane().setContent(root);
        dialog.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

And this is my LoadResourcesHelper class:

```
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class LoadResourcesHelper {

    private LoadResourcesHelper() {

    }

    public static Parent loadFXML(String resource) {
        Parent root = null;

        try {
            new FXMLLoader();
            root = FXMLLoader.load(new LoadResourcesHelper().getClass().getResource("sms/views/" + ".fxml"));
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(LoadResourcesHelper.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        return root;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the paths to the 3 files? You are not adding the String resource to the path so I'd try changing it to FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("sms/views/" + resource + ".fxml")); and then root = loader.load();

Comment: Thanks for your help @LuciferUchiha but still got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Solved! It was the `/` before the path, the path to file should have been `"/sms/views/" + resourse + ".fxml"` and not `"sms/views/" + resourse + ".fxml"` .